# How to on the fly copy changes in wwwroot source directory to publish directory

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I do a lot of JavaScript development on a .Net Core web site. The dev site is hosted under IIS. As a result, when I change a .js file in the wwwroot directory in my source tree, I then have to publish the web project to make my change show up in my dev site. Which can take a while and is a pain.

Is it possible to automatically copy any changes I make in my wwwroot directory to its counterpart in the publish directory whenever I change a file in wwwroot?

Comment: Have you tried a gulp task that watches your file and copies it when it changes?

Comment: Well for local development you have IIS Express or can run the app as project (runs in console window). You should deploy/publish your app to an iis / development/staging server once your changes are ready/finished with it

Comment: I agree with @Tseng. By having auto updates you could end up breaking something on your live site by mistake.

Comment: @Sefe No I haven't. It has to be really responsive, so I was hoping for for example a Windows program that ties in with the Windows OS file change events.

Comment: @Tseng I can't get away from IIS on the dev boxes for now.

Comment: @el_M The publish directory sits on the developer box. The live site sits on a separate web server.

Comment: I run my gulp watch tasks when I run my website and it is working fine (and responsively). I am copying files from my working folder *into* the wwwroot, but nothing stops you to copy out of the wwwroot.

Comment: @user1147862 if you are using visual studio, you can use a shortcut: `alt` + `;`, `alt` + `P` which will publish whatever is selected. Otherwise what you are looking for is continues deliver.